# Reference multiple cells to create summary sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have a multiple worksheets within one workbook and am trying to pull several consistent cells from those worksheets into one summary worksheet. I do not know if there is a formula or a macro that I can use easily. Ideally I would like to enter the worksheet name in one cell and the formula auto populate the cells from the worksheet into the cells listed below.

Situation:
Worksheet names:
Reg 12.08, 
Qtr 12. 08, 
Reg 12.11, 
Qtr 12.11, 
Reg 12.13, 
Qtr 12.13, 
….

Summary worksheet:
Row 1 would be for worksheet Reg 12. 08, 
A1 – I will enter the worksheet reference (Reg 12.08), 
B1 – would reference B1 in Reg 12.08, 
C1 – would reference B10 in Reg 12.08, 
D1 – would reference B2 in Reg 12.08, 
E1 – would reference B8 in Reg 12.08,

Row 2 would repeat the same cell references from Qtr 12.08

And so on…

I also will be adding more worksheets and would like it to be easy to have the same cell locations in new worksheets be listed in the summary.

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: Would `=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!B1")` work in Summary B1?

Comment: It seems like your data should really be organized in a different way...

Answer (score 2):

### INDIRECT FUNCTION

Try `INDIRECT` [function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

> Returns the reference specified by a text string. References are immediately evaluated to display their contents. Use INDIRECT when you want to change the reference to a cell within a formula without changing the formula itself.

Some example from [spreadsheetpage.com-Referencing A Sheet Indirectly](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/referencing_a_sheet_indirectly/). Question answered there:

> Is there any way that I can enter the month name into a cell on my summary sheet, and then have my formulas use the data for the specified sheet?
>
> Yes. Excel's INDIRECT function was designed specifically for this sort of thing. This function accepts a text string as an argument, and then evaluates the text string to arrive at a cell or range reference. In your case, assume that cell B1 on your summary worksheet holds the month name. The following formula utilizes the INDIRECT function to create the range reference used by the SUM function:
>
> =SUM(INDIRECT(B1&"!F1:F10"))

### Syntax:

`INDIRECT(ref_text, [a1])`

> Ref_text    Required. A reference to a cell that contains an A1-style reference, an R1C1-style reference, a name defined as a reference, or a reference to a cell as a text string.
>
> A1    Optional. A logical value that specifies what type of reference is contained in the cell ref_text.

### Examples:

1. `=INDIRECT("MySheet1!C1")` will return value from cell C1 on
   sheet "MySheet1"
2. `=INDIRECT("MySheet" & A1 &"!C1")` will return
   value from cell C1 on variable worksheet "MySheet1", "MySheet2",
   etc. if the A1 contains 1,2, etc.
3. `=INDIRECT("'Reg 12.08'!C1")`
   will return value from cell C1 on sheet "Reg 12.08"
4. `=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!" & C1)` will return value from a variable range defined in C1, on variable worksheet, defined in cell A1.